# How to save ListView item index after filtering it?

Tags: java, android, search

It's very common question, but I still can not found suitable solution. I have an input search function in the ListView. After I input smth there is new ListView with suitable items presented. But this new ListView is not updated, I mean index of items are not updated. So the main problem is: how to save actual item index when show it in the new ListView after search? 
Here is code for input search function

```
inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            MainActivity.this.mAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        }
    });
```

I tried many methods to solve this problem including `listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`, but it's not successful. Could anybody tell just in common how to solve this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Update question with `adapter` code

Comment: Which method should I use?